# How to display Si in table layout in android textview

Tags: android, android-tablelayout

In the below code I am displaying the details in the form of table. Now all the details a are coming from JSON array and that details are displaying in a table layout.

In the same way I want to display the SI but this field is not in the database.

Expected output:

```
SI
1
2
3
|
|
| etc
```

Based on number of patients I want to display the SI numbers.

**updated Answer**

```
    public class General_patient_list extends Activity {

    String data = "";
    TableLayout tl;
    TableRow tr;
   TextView si;
    String queryString;
    int numOfPatients = 0;
   TextView[] snos;
    TextView[] regnos;
    TextView[] patNames;
    TextView[] sex;
    TextView[] regdates;
    TextView[] adress;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.general_collection_report);

        tl = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.maintable);
        final String date1 = getIntent().getStringExtra("date1");
        final String date2 = getIntent().getStringExtra("date2");


        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                queryString = "date1=" + date1 + "&date2="
                        + date2;
                data = DatabaseUtility.executeQueryPhp("general_registration",queryString);
                System.out.println(data);

                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        ArrayList<Patients> patients = parseJSON(data);
                        numOfPatients = patients.size();
                        addData(patients);                     
                    }
                });

            }
        }).start();
    }

    public ArrayList<Patients> parseJSON(String data) {
        ArrayList<Patients> patients = new ArrayList<Patients>();
        try {
            JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(data);
            for (int i = 0; i < jArray.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
                Patients patient = new Patients();
                //patient.setSi(json_data.getInt("si"));
                patient.setRegno(json_data.getString("reg_no"));
               patient.setPat_name(json_data.getString("name"));
               patient.setSex(json_data.getString("sex"));
                patient.setReg_date(json_data.getString("entry_date"));
               patient.setAddress(json_data.getString("address"));
                patients.add(patient);
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e("log_tag", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());  
        }
        return patients;
    }

    void addHeader(){
        /** Create a TableRow dynamically **/
        tr = new TableRow(this);

        /** Creating a TextView to add to the row **/
        si = new TextView(this);
        si.setText("SI");
        si.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
               LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        si.setPadding(5, 5, 5, 5);
        si.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#rrggbb"));
        LinearLayout Ll = new LinearLayout(this);
      LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        params.setMargins(5, 5, 5, 5);
        //Ll.setPadding(10, 5, 5, 5);
       Ll.addView(si,params);
        tr.addView((View)Ll); // Adding textView to tablerow.

        /** Creating Qty Button **/
        TextView reg_no = new TextView(this);
        reg_no.setText("Reg_No");
        reg_no.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        reg_no.setPadding(5, 5, 5, 5);
        reg_no.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
        Ll = new LinearLayout(this);
        params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        params.setMargins(0, 5, 5, 5);
        //Ll.setPadding(10, 5, 5, 5);
        Ll.addView(reg_no,params);
        tr.addView((View)Ll); // Adding textview to tablerow.

        /** Creating Qty Button **/
       TextView pat_name = new TextView(this);
        pat_name.setText("Patient Name");
        pat_name.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        pat_name.setPadding(5, 5, 5, 5);
        pat_name.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
        Ll = new LinearLayout(this);
        params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        params.setMargins(0, 5, 5, 5);
        //Ll.setPadding(10, 5, 5, 5);
        Ll.addView(pat_name,params);
        tr.addView((View)Ll); // Adding textview to tablerow.

        /** Creating Qty Button **/
        TextView sex = new TextView(this);
        sex.setText("Sex");
        sex.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        sex.setPadding(5, 5, 5, 5);
        sex.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
        Ll = new LinearLayout(this);
        params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        params.setMargins(0, 5, 5, 5);
        //Ll.setPadding(10, 5, 5, 5);
        Ll.addView(sex,params);
        tr.addView((View)Ll); // Adding textview to tablerow.

        /** Creating Qty Button **/
        TextView reg_date = new TextView(this);
        reg_date.setText("Registration Date");
        reg_date.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        reg_date.setPadding(5, 5, 5, 5);
        reg_date.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
        Ll = new LinearLayout(this);
        params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        params.setMargins(0, 5, 5, 5);
        //Ll.setPadding(10, 5, 5, 5);
        Ll.addView(reg_date,params);
        tr.addView((View)Ll); // Adding textview to tablerow.

        /** Creating Qty Button **/
        TextView address = new TextView(this);
        address.setText("Address");
        address.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        address.setPadding(5, 5, 5, 5);
        address.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
        Ll = new LinearLayout(this);
        params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        params.setMargins(0, 5, 5, 5);
        //Ll.setPadding(10, 5, 5, 5);
        Ll.addView(address,params);
        tr.addView((View)Ll); // Adding textview to tablerow.

         // Add the TableRow to the TableLayout
        tl.addView(tr, new TableLayout.LayoutParams(
                LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    }

    @SuppressWarnings({ "rawtypes", "deprecation" })
    public void addData(ArrayList<Patients> patients) {

        snos = new TextView[numOfPatients];
        regnos = new TextView[numOfPatients];
        patNames=new TextView[numOfPatients];
        sex=new TextView[numOfPatients];
        regdates=new TextView[numOfPatients];
        adress=new TextView[numOfPatients];
        int j = 0;

        addHeader();



        for (Iterator i = patients.iterator(); i.hasNext();) {


            snos[j] = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.si);
            regnos[j] = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.regno);
            patNames[j]=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.patname);
            sex[j]=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.sex);
            regdates[j]=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.regdate);
            adress[j]=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.adress);

            Patients p = (Patients) i.next();

            /** Create a TableRow dynamically **/
            tr = new TableRow(this);

           if(j % 2==0){
               tr.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
           }
               else{

                   tr.setBackgroundColor(Color.GRAY);  
               }



            /** Creating a TextView to add to the row **/
           snos[j] = new TextView(this);
           int temp = j;
           snos[j].setText(String.valueOf(temp +1));
           snos[j].setId(j);
           snos[j].setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                    LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
           snos[j].setPadding(5, 5, 5, 5);
          // snos[j].setBackgroundColor(Color.GRAY);
            LinearLayout Ll = new LinearLayout(this);
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                    LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            params.setMargins(5, 2, 2, 2);
            Ll.setPadding(10, 5, 5, 5);
            Ll.addView(snos[j],params);
            tr.addView((View)Ll); // Adding textView to tablerow.

            /** Creating Qty Button **/
            regnos[j] = new TextView(this);
            regnos[j].setKeyListener(null);
            regnos[j].setText(p.getRegno());
            regnos[j].setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                    LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
            regnos[j].setPadding(5, 5, 5, 5);
         //   regnos[j].setBackgroundColor(Color.GRAY);
            Ll = new LinearLayout(this);

            params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                    LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            params.setMargins(0, 2, 2, 2);
            //Ll.setPadding(10, 5, 5, 5);
            Ll.addView(regnos[j],params);
            tr.addView((View)Ll); // Adding textview to tablerow.

            /** Creating Qty Button **/
            patNames[j] = new TextView(this);
            patNames[j].setKeyListener(null);
            patNames[j].setText(p.getPat_name());
            patNames[j].setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                    LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
            patNames[j].setPadding(5, 5, 5, 5);
          //  patNames[j].setBackgroundColor(Color.GRAY);
            Ll = new LinearLayout(this);
            params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                    LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            params.setMargins(0, 2, 2, 2);
            //Ll.setPadding(10, 5, 5, 5);
            Ll.addView(patNames[j],params);
            tr.addView((View)Ll); // Adding textview to tablerow.

            /** Creating Qty Button **/
            sex[j] = new TextView(this);
            sex[j].setKeyListener(null);
            sex[j].setText(p.getSex());
            sex[j].setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                    LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
            sex[j].setPadding(5, 5, 5, 5);
           // sex[j].setBackgroundColor(Color.GRAY);
            Ll = new LinearLayout(this);
            params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                    LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            params.setMargins(0, 2, 2, 2);
            //Ll.setPadding(10, 5, 5, 5);
            Ll.addView(sex[j],params);
            tr.addView((View)Ll); // Adding textview to tablerow.

            /** Creating Qty Button **/
            regdates[j] = new TextView(this);
            regdates[j].setKeyListener(null);
            regdates[j].setText(p.getReg_date());
            regdates[j].setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                    LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
            regdates[j].setPadding(5, 5, 5, 5);
         //   regdates[j].setBackgroundColor(Color.GRAY);
            Ll = new LinearLayout(this);
            params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                    LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            params.setMargins(0, 2, 2, 2);
            //Ll.setPadding(10, 5, 5, 5);
            Ll.addView(regdates[j],params);
            tr.addView((View)Ll); // Adding textview to tablerow.

            /** Creating Qty Button **/
            adress[j] = new TextView(this);
            adress[j].setKeyListener(null);
            adress[j].setText(p.getAddress());
            adress[j].setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                    LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
            adress[j].setPadding(5, 5, 5, 5);
        //    adress[j].setBackgroundColor(Color.GRAY);
            Ll = new LinearLayout(this);
            params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                    LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            params.setMargins(0, 2, 2, 2);
            //Ll.setPadding(10, 5, 5, 5);
            Ll.addView(adress[j],params);
            tr.addView((View)Ll); // Adding textview to tablerow.

             // Add the TableRow to the TableLayout
            tl.addView(tr, new TableLayout.LayoutParams(
                    LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                    LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
            j++;
        }
    }
```

Comment: so you want to add an extra column at the start and put index in that. is it ?

Comment: yes I was already added new column I want to display only index number that should start from 1

Comment: is the column name "Reg_No" ?

Comment: @dora yes that is the column name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public class General_patient_list extends Activity {

    String data = "";
    TableLayout tl;
    TableRow tr;
    TextView label;
    String queryString;
    int numOfPatients = 0;
   TextView[] snos;
    TextView[] regnos;
    TextView[] patNames;
    TextView[] sex;
    TextView[] regdates;
    TextView[] adress;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.general_collection_report);

        tl = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.maintable);
        final String date1 = getIntent().getStringExtra("date1");
        final String date2 = getIntent().getStringExtra("date2");


        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                queryString = "date1=" + date1 + "&date2="
                        + date2;
                data = DatabaseUtility.executeQueryPhp("general_registration",queryString);
                System.out.println(data);

                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        ArrayList<Patients> patients = parseJSON(data);
                        numOfPatients = patients.size();
                        addData(patients);                     
                    }
                });

            }
        }).start();
    }

    public ArrayList<Patients> parseJSON(String data) {
        ArrayList<Patients> patients = new ArrayList<Patients>();
        try {
            JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(data);
            for (int i = 0; i < jArray.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
                Patients patient = new Patients();
                //patient.setSi(json_data.getInt("si"));
                patient.setRegno(json_data.getString("reg_no"));
               patient.setPat_name(json_data.getString("name"));
               patient.setSex(json_data.getString("sex"));
                patient.setReg_date(json_data.getString("entry_date"));
               patient.setAddress(json_data.getString("address"));
                patients.add(patient);
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e("log_tag", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());  
        }
        return patients;
    }

    void addHeader(){
        /** Create a TableRow dynamically **/
        tr = new TableRow(this);

        /** Creating a TextView to add to the row **/
        TextView  si = new TextView(this);
        si.setText("Si");
        si.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
               LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        si.setPadding(5, 5, 5, 5);
        si.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
        LinearLayout Ll = new LinearLayout(this);
      LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        params.setMargins(5, 5, 5, 5);
        Ll.setPadding(10, 5, 5, 5);
       Ll.addView(si,params);
        tr.addView((View)Ll); // Adding textView to tablerow.

        /** Creating Qty Button **/
        TextView reg_no = new TextView(this);
        reg_no.setText("Reg_No");
        reg_no.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        reg_no.setPadding(5, 5, 5, 5);
        reg_no.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);

        params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        params.setMargins(0, 5, 5, 5);
        //Ll.setPadding(10, 5, 5, 5);
        Ll.addView(reg_no,params);
        tr.addView((View)Ll); // Adding textview to tablerow.

        /** Creating Qty Button **/
       TextView pat_name = new TextView(this);
        pat_name.setText("Patient Name");
        pat_name.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        pat_name.setPadding(5, 5, 5, 5);
        pat_name.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
        Ll = new LinearLayout(this);
        params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        params.setMargins(0, 5, 5, 5);
        //Ll.setPadding(10, 5, 5, 5);
        Ll.addView(pat_name,params);
        tr.addView((View)Ll); // Adding textview to tablerow.

        /** Creating Qty Button **/
        TextView sex = new TextView(this);
        sex.setText("Sex");
        sex.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        sex.setPadding(5, 5, 5, 5);
        sex.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
        Ll = new LinearLayout(this);
        params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        params.setMargins(0, 5, 5, 5);
        //Ll.setPadding(10, 5, 5, 5);
        Ll.addView(sex,params);
        tr.addView((View)Ll); // Adding textview to tablerow.

        /** Creating Qty Button **/
        TextView reg_date = new TextView(this);
        reg_date.setText("Registration Date");
        reg_date.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        reg_date.setPadding(5, 5, 5, 5);
        reg_date.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
        Ll = new LinearLayout(this);
        params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        params.setMargins(0, 5, 5, 5);
        //Ll.setPadding(10, 5, 5, 5);
        Ll.addView(reg_date,params);
        tr.addView((View)Ll); // Adding textview to tablerow.

        /** Creating Qty Button **/
        TextView address = new TextView(this);
        address.setText("Address");
        address.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        address.setPadding(5, 5, 5, 5);
        address.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
        Ll = new LinearLayout(this);
        params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        params.setMargins(0, 5, 5, 5);
        //Ll.setPadding(10, 5, 5, 5);
        Ll.addView(address,params);
        tr.addView((View)Ll); // Adding textview to tablerow.

         // Add the TableRow to the TableLayout
        tl.addView(tr, new TableLayout.LayoutParams(
                LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    }

    @SuppressWarnings({ "rawtypes", "deprecation" })
    public void addData(ArrayList<Patients> patients) {

        snos = new TextView[numOfPatients];
        regnos = new TextView[numOfPatients];
        patNames=new TextView[numOfPatients];
        sex=new TextView[numOfPatients];
        regdates=new TextView[numOfPatients];
        adress=new TextView[numOfPatients];
        int j = 0;

        addHeader();



        for (Iterator i = patients.iterator(); i.hasNext();) {


            //snos[j] = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.si);
            //regnos[j] = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.regno);
            //patNames[j]=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.patname);
            //sex[j]=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.sex);
            //regdates[j]=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.regdate);
            //adress[j]=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.adress);

            Patients p = (Patients) i.next();

            /** Create a TableRow dynamically **/
            tr = new TableRow(this);

           if(j % 2==0){
               tr.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
           }
               else{

                   tr.setBackgroundColor(Color.GRAY);  
               }



            /** Creating a TextView to add to the row **/
           snos[j] = new TextView(this);
           int temp = j;
           snos[j].setText(String.valueOf(temp +1));
           snos[j].setId(j);
           snos[j].setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                    LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
           snos[j].setPadding(5, 5, 5, 5);
          // snos[j].setBackgroundColor(Color.GRAY);
            LinearLayout Ll = new LinearLayout(this);
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                    LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            params.setMargins(5, 2, 2, 2);
            Ll.setPadding(10, 5, 5, 5);
            Ll.addView(snos[j],params);
            tr.addView((View)Ll); // Adding textView to tablerow.

            /** Creating Qty Button **/
            regnos[j] = new TextView(this);
            regnos[j].setKeyListener(null);
            regnos[j].setText(p.getRegno());
            regnos[j].setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                    LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
            regnos[j].setPadding(5, 5, 5, 5);
         //   regnos[j].setBackgroundColor(Color.GRAY);
            Ll = new LinearLayout(this);
            params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                    LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            params.setMargins(0, 2, 2, 2);
            //Ll.setPadding(10, 5, 5, 5);
            Ll.addView(regnos[j],params);
            tr.addView((View)Ll); // Adding textview to tablerow.

            /** Creating Qty Button **/
            patNames[j] = new TextView(this);
            patNames[j].setKeyListener(null);
            patNames[j].setText(p.getPat_name());
            patNames[j].setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                    LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
            patNames[j].setPadding(5, 5, 5, 5);
          //  patNames[j].setBackgroundColor(Color.GRAY);
            Ll = new LinearLayout(this);
            params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                    LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            params.setMargins(0, 2, 2, 2);
            //Ll.setPadding(10, 5, 5, 5);
            Ll.addView(patNames[j],params);
            tr.addView((View)Ll); // Adding textview to tablerow.

            /** Creating Qty Button **/
            sex[j] = new TextView(this);
            sex[j].setKeyListener(null);
            sex[j].setText(p.getSex());
            sex[j].setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                    LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
            sex[j].setPadding(5, 5, 5, 5);
           // sex[j].setBackgroundColor(Color.GRAY);
            Ll = new LinearLayout(this);
            params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                    LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            params.setMargins(0, 2, 2, 2);
            //Ll.setPadding(10, 5, 5, 5);
            Ll.addView(sex[j],params);
            tr.addView((View)Ll); // Adding textview to tablerow.

            /** Creating Qty Button **/
            regdates[j] = new TextView(this);
            regdates[j].setKeyListener(null);
            regdates[j].setText(p.getReg_date());
            regdates[j].setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                    LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
            regdates[j].setPadding(5, 5, 5, 5);
         //   regdates[j].setBackgroundColor(Color.GRAY);
            Ll = new LinearLayout(this);
            params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                    LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            params.setMargins(0, 2, 2, 2);
            //Ll.setPadding(10, 5, 5, 5);
            Ll.addView(regdates[j],params);
            tr.addView((View)Ll); // Adding textview to tablerow.

            /** Creating Qty Button **/
            adress[j] = new TextView(this);
            adress[j].setKeyListener(null);
            adress[j].setText(p.getAddress());
            adress[j].setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                    LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
            adress[j].setPadding(5, 5, 5, 5);
        //    adress[j].setBackgroundColor(Color.GRAY);
            Ll = new LinearLayout(this);
            params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                    LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            params.setMargins(0, 2, 2, 2);
            //Ll.setPadding(10, 5, 5, 5);
            Ll.addView(adress[j],params);
            tr.addView((View)Ll); // Adding textview to tablerow.

             // Add the TableRow to the TableLayout
            tl.addView(tr, new TableLayout.LayoutParams(
                    LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                    LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
            j++;
        }
    }
```

I am not sure if that is what you want.I hope it helps.